# How to use sql with optional query params in JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I have the following `sql` template that I want to use with `JdbcTemplate`:

```
select * from table1
where (@param1 is null or col1 = @param1)
  and (@param2 is null or col2 = @param2)
```

What is special here is that "param1" and "param2" can be used as optional params to restrict the query.

Problem: how can I now make use of that optional params? I mean, how do I have to provide them for the `JdbcTemplate`?

Probably similar to the following pseudocode:

```
@Service
public class DatabaseService {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @Autowired
    private SqlResourceHandler handler;

    public void getEntries(String param1, String param2) {
        String sql = handler.getSql(); //does not matter where sql comes from
        jdbc.queryForList(sql, param1, param2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160468/jdbctemplate-optional-parameters

Comment: @Cata I'm looking for a solution where I could use a prepared statement or prepared sql. The linked question just suggests of rebuilding the sql entirely on each request... that's not nice...

Comment: mmm, the only option that I know is declaring a dynamic SQL: https://sqlstudies.com/2017/02/27/queries-with-optional-parameters/. What do you think?. Actually, I'm interested in the answer now haha.